# Africover data, where is it now located?

Tags: data, africa

Africover geographic data used to be at http://www.africover.org. It is no longer here. Where is the Africover data now located?

Comment: I think data questions like this are best researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the search keywords you used before posting but which were unsuccessful in locating the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of Africover, but a quick search leads me to the *Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations*' [GeoNetwork](http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/main.search?title=africover) pages, which appears to have a database of Africover geographic datasets available.

Comment: @L.Scott If this has answered your question, please consider upvoting and marking as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)